# Overriding a default option(...) value in CMake from a parent CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, build, build-process, cmake

I am trying to include several third-party libraries in my source tree with minimal changes to their build system for ease of upgrading. They all use CMake, as do I, so in my own CMakeLists.txt I can use `add_subdirectory(extern/foo)` for libfoo.

But the foo CMakeLists.txt compiles a test harness, builds documentation, a shared library which I don't need, and so on. The libfoo authors had the foresight to control these via options - `option(FOO_BUILD_SHARED "Build libfoo shared library" ON)` for example - which means I can set them via the CMake command line. But I would like to make that off by default and overridable via the command line.

I have tried doing `set(FOO_BUILD_SHARED OFF)` before `add_subdirectory(extern/foo)`. That has the effect of not trying to build the shared library during the second and subsequent build attempts, but not during the first one, which is the one I really need to speed up.

Is this possible, or do I need to maintain forked CMakeLists.txt for these projects?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try setting the variable in the CACHE

```
SET(FOO_BUILD_SHARED OFF CACHE BOOL "Build libfoo shared library")
```

Note: You need to specify the variable type and a description so CMake knows how to display this entry in the GUI.

Comment: Put it before the add_subdirectory command, so it will set the default value for the variable.

Comment: Sometimes you need to use the `FORCE`

Comment: Pro tip (to myself): `FORCE` goes after the doc string, not randomly in the middle...

Comment: @Rajish If the variable is already cached due to a previous `OPTION` or `SET( CACHE )` call or a CMakeCache.txt from a previous configure, you have to use `SET(FOO_BUILD_SHARED OFF CACHE BOOL "Build libfoo shared library" FORCE)`. [source](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html)

Comment: Won't INTERNAL do?

Comment: **Use `INTERNAL` instead of `BOOL` if want to hide option (from CMake GUI).** Anyway, what about `cmake_dependent_option`? Does this work for that as well?

Answer (score 11):

This question is rather old but Google brought me here.

The problem with `SET(<variable name> <value> CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)` is that it will set the option project wide. If you want to use a sub-project, which is a library, and you want to set `BUILD_STATIC_LIBS` for the sub-project (`ParentLibrary`) using `SET(... CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)` it will set the value for all projects.

I'm using the following project structure:

```
|CMakeLists.txt (root)
|- dependencies
   | CMakeLists.txt (dependencies)
   |- ParentLibrary
      | CMakeLists.txt (parent)
|- lib
   | CMakeLists.txt (lib)
```

Now I have `CMakeLists.txt (dependencies)` which looks like this:

```
# Copy the option you want to change from ParentLibrary here
option (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" ON)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
add_subdirectory(ParentLibrary)
```

Advantage is that I don't have to modify `ParentLibrary` and that I can set the option only for that project.

It is necessary to explicitly copy the `option` command from the `ParentLibrary` as otherwise when executing CMake configuration initially the value of the variable would first be set by the `set` command and later the value would be overwritten by the `option` command because there was no value in the cache. When executing CMake configuration for the second time the `option` command would be ignored because there is already a value in the cache and the value from the `set` command would be used. This would lead to some strange behavior that the configuration between two CMake runs would be different.

Comment: Good idea, but to be precise, the option will be valid for all sub-projects under dependencies, not only for one.

Answer (score 5):

*To give a more current answer, since newer projects use newer CMake versions (probably with libraries which use old CMake versions).*

As of CMake 3.13 there is an option to simply set a variable in the parent project, which sets the variable in all sub projects. This is basically what you've tried, but now it is possible. Version 3.13 introduced [CMP0077](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0077.html):

> The option() command is typically used to create a cache entry to allow users to set the option. However, there are cases in which a normal (non-cached) variable of the same name as the option may be defined by the project prior to calling the option() command. For example, a project that embeds another project as a subdirectory may want to hard-code options of the subproject to build the way it needs.
> ...
> In CMake 3.13 and above the option() command prefers to do nothing when a normal variable of the given name already exists. It does not create or update a cache entry or remove the normal variable. The new behavior is consistent between the first and later runs in a build tree. This policy provides compatibility with projects that have not been updated to expect the new behavior.

So you can simply use `set` to hardcode an option inside the parent project, by adding the following before `add_subdirectory`:

```
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077 NEW)
set(FOO_BUILD_SHARED OFF)

...

add_subdirectory(extern/foo)
```