# Override option in CMake subproject

Tags: cmake, project

I'm trying to reuse the `CMakeLists.txt` of a third-party project whose source I don't want to change ([expat](https://github.com/alamaison/winsparkle/blob/master/3rdparty/expat/CMakeLists.txt), to be exact).  I've added the project as a subproject of the top level using `add_subdirectory`.

This works but now I would like to set the value of some of the subproject's `option`s in the top level `CMakeLists.txt`.  How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding a default option(...) value in CMake from a parent CMakeLists.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766740/overriding-a-default-option-value-in-cmake-from-a-parent-cmakelists-txt)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

See [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766740/overriding-a-default-option-value-in-cmake-from-a-parent-cmakelists-txt)  with a good answer.

Answer in short:

```
SET(SOME_EXPAT_OPTION OFF CACHE BOOL "Use some expat option")
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for Visual Studio generators in my case (CMake 3.4.0), but works fine for Makefiles generators.
Other answers suggest to use  *option* that works fine for both Visual Studio and Makefiles generators.

Comment: How can we do it from the command line? I have one set of options that I invoke `cmake` with for LLVM, but one subproject seems to need an extra option.

Comment: @ronkot Like in your linked answer, I would add, that sometimes it is necessary to add `FORCE` as additional parameter after the description string.

Answer (score 55):

If the sub-project uses `option` (not `set`) for its configuration settings, then you can specify values using `option` before adding the subdirectory:

```
option(LIB_OPTION1 "" OFF)
option(LIB_OPTION2 "" ON)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/lib)
```

Comment: What if the sub project doesn't use `option`, but uses `set`, is there a way to override existing uses of `set` without using cache?

Answer (score 7):

You can define the options with the desired settings (ON or OFF) before calling `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY`. This will then take precedence over the `OPTION` commands in expat's `CMakeLists.txt` since the last parameter to `OPTION` is only a *default* value (which is neglected if that settings already exists).

Comment: I tried that but it had no effect.  I think the trick is to use `CACHE` as in @kullero's answer

Comment: @thehouse I was pretty sure that the `OPTION` command caches its effect and I just tried and it works. Of course, the value may not be in cache already, but that is true for the `SET` command as well unless you use `FORCE`. I have to admit that the `SET` way is more generic since `OPTION` only allows boolean values, but in the end that was what you asked for.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your original answer.  I thought you meant define the option using `SET`.  I see what you mean now so upvoted.

Answer (score -2):

The SET-command has the 'PARENT_SCOPE' option:

```
If PARENT_SCOPE is present, the variable will be set in the scope above the current
scope. Each new directory or function creates a new scope. This command will set the 
value of a variable into the parent directory or calling function (whichever is 
applicable to the case at hand). PARENT_SCOPE cannot be combined with CACHE.
```

(see: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:set )

Comment: Does this not do the opposite of what I'm after?  I'm trying to get a variable in the parent scope to affect a subscope.