# How to include existing CMake git repo as submodule in my own CMake project?

Tags: c++, linux, build, cmake, openkinect

I am trying to write some program using the [OpenKinect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) project. I want to add the OpenKinect's master branch as a subdirectory to my project's source. But, if you look into the OpenKinect's own CMake, there is too much stuff there, and I do not need everything. There are certain options there, which are being set to ON or OFF, like this:

```
OPTION(BUILD_AUDIO "Build audio support" OFF)
OPTION(BUILD_REDIST_PACKAGE "Build libfreenect in a legally-redistributable manner (only affects audio)" OFF)
OPTION(BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build example programs" ON)
OPTION(BUILD_FAKENECT "Build fakenect mock library" ON)
OPTION(BUILD_C_SYNC "Build c synchronous library" ON)
OPTION(BUILD_CPP "Build C++ Library (currently header only)" ON)
OPTION(BUILD_CV "Build OpenCV wrapper" ON)
OPTION(BUILD_AS3_SERVER "Build the Actionscript 3 Server Example" OFF)
OPTION(BUILD_PYTHON "Build Python extension" ON)
IF(PROJECT_OS_LINUX)
    OPTION(BUILD_CPACK "Build an RPM or DEB using CPack" ON)
ENDIF(PROJECT_OS_LINUX)
```

Without making any major changes to the OpenKinect files (so that I can `git pull` any time I need to), how do I import only some parts (e.g., the `C++ wrapper` and the `OpenCV bindings`) to my own CMake project? I thought of copying certain directories, which are not dependent on the other directories, if I completely re-write the CMake files. I would not be able to use the git any more, but it would be a quick fix. But I am getting strange errors that way, such as "stdexcept was not not declared in this scope", which makes no sense, because it is a standard gc++ library.

Comment: Why not "fork" OpenKinect and keep your changes in a separate branch. That way you can keep "pulling" in updates from git-OpenKinect, while keeping your "modifications" on a separate branch. Then you could do what Johannes S suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want to enable/disable some parts of that library, you can simply set the appropriate options before calling `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY`.

Simply use the same OPTION commands  as in the library's `CMakeLists.txt` but set them `ON`/`OFF` as you need. Of course, oyu are free to change/choose the describing string as you like.

Alternatively (and if options have a different value than true/false), you can use the `SET(.... CACHE ... )`

e.g.

```
SET(BUILD_CPP TRUE CACHE BOOL "Build C++ Library (currently header only)")
```

Similar question: 
[Override option in CMake subproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061605/override-option-in-cmake-subproject)

Comment: But this implies changing the CMakeLists.txt of OpenKinect, which is not desired...

Comment: No, not at all. Just set them in *your* CMakeLists.txt before calling `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(....)` to include OpenKinect. All settings/variables are inherited by the subproject.

Comment: Did it work for you? If yes, it would be nice if you could accept the answer. If not, please let us know what is missing.

Comment: I had somehow missed it. Sincerest apologies :(