# How to override dependency of 3rd-party cmake project?

Tags: c++, cmake

My CMake project depends on `zipper` library which is a wrapper on top of minizip/zlib. The `zipper` is a git submodule (in `/thirdparty/zipper` directory) of my project and so I compile it with the `add_subdirectory` command:

**/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
add_subdirectory(../../thirdparty thirdparty)
```

**/thirdparty/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
add_subdirectory(zlib)
add_subdirectory(zipper)
```

When I compile the `thirdparty` project it compiles zlib and zipper independently, so the `zipper` looks for `zlib` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but I want `zipper` to link again just compiled `zlibstatic` near it. How to do that?

Comment: Maybe this question helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/14061605/1741542

Comment: @OlafDietsche yes, I have done this already for few my libraries, but zipper does not seem to have such options :(

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know anything about CMake. Looking at https://github.com/sebastiandev/zipper/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L107, maybe you can set an environment variable `ZLIBROOT`, where CMake looks for the library. Although, this depends on the order CMake searches.