# Specifying Build Options for External CMake Dependency

Tags: build, cmake

I am in the process of writing my project's CMakeLists.txt file. My project relies on an external dependency, [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw), luckily for me GLFW also uses CMake for its build system. I am using find_package() and git submodules to handle dependency management, currently this is how my CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
# CMake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
# project name
project(CHIP-8)

# dependency management
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

find_package(glfw)
if(NOT glfw)
    message("Unable to locate glfw.")

    message("Cloning the repository.")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND
        git submodule update --init -- libs
        WORKING_DIRECTORY
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )

    message("Building glfw.")
    add_subdirectory(libs/glfw)
endif()
```

From my limited understanding of CMake the command `add_subdirectory(libs/glfw)` runs CMake on the recently cloned glfw sub-module. The problem is a lot of unnecessary features are part of the default build for GLFW such as examples, unit tests, and documentation.

The [documentation for compiling GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile.html#compile_options) lists the CMake options for disabling these features `GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES`, `GLFW_BUILD_TESTS`, and `GLFW_BUILD_DOCS`.

I have two questions, the first being how can I specify these options, and the second is the argument I pass for find_package accurate (I do have GLFW installed on my system yet every time I build it still attempts to clone and build the repository).

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061605/override-option-in-cmake-subproject).
All I had to do was add:

```
option(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
option(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
option(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF)
```

right before `add_subdirectory(libs/glfw)`.