# cmake set value of variable for first run after command "project"

Tags: c++, variables, caching, cmake

If in my `CMakeLists.txt` I have (order #1)

```
...
set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON  CACHE BOOL "ON")
project ("my_project")
...
```

on first run I get in `ccmake`

```
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE          *ON
```

But if I invert the order of `set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ...` and `project ...` (order #2)

```
...
project ("my_project")
set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON  CACHE BOOL "ON")
...
```

I get on first run

```
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE          *OFF
```

Since I have many projects largely sharing configuration, I want to have a common `CMakeLsts.txt`, and a project-specific `CMakeLsts.txt` with the minimum project-specific contents, and an include

```
project ("my_project")
set (COMMON_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../common")
include ("${COMMON_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt")
```

and setting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` in `${COMMON_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt`.
So I seem to be forced to work with order #2.

Under these conditions,

1. Only having the minimum project-specific contents in the project `CMakeLsts.txt` (so excluding setting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON`).
2. Setting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` for the first run in the common `CMakeLsts.txt`.

**what are (perhaps more than one) possible ways of getting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` on first run, and then using the cache?**

From what I tried, using `FORCE` is not useful, since if I change the value to something different (`OFF` in this case), it will revert the value to `ON` with each run.
I wouldn't want to move setting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` to my project-specific `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Related**

1. [Overriding a default option(...) value in CMake from a parent CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766740/overriding-a-default-option-value-in-cmake-from-a-parent-cmakelists-txt)

Comment: This is the precise reason why [presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) exist.

Comment: Also, are you aware of the `--verbose` argument to `cmake --build ...` or the `VERBOSE=1` environment variable that the makefile generators respect?

Comment: @AlexReinking - So you mean that with my "simple" `include ("${COMMON_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt")` and appropriate commands (and abiding by conditions #1 and #2) it is not possible to work this out?
(besides the fact that presets would cover this job).

Comment: @AlexReinking - I think I had used it long ago, but I would have to read about it again to use it properly.

Comment: You just set the environment variable... docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/VERBOSE.html

Comment: @AlexReinking - 
`VERBOSE=1 make` produced verbose output.
`VERBOSE=1 ccmake ..` did not produce `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON`, my main objective. So it is a generally useful flag, although since it does not produce any persistent configuration, it is somewhat distant from my objective.

Comment: You should pass this in via a source evaluated before the project files are parsed. In decreasing order of my preference those would be cmake presets, cache initialization script and toolchain file, that is assuming you don't want to pass the value using `-D CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=1` during configuration. Imho this is an option that should be chosen by the user though, so I certainly wouldn't hardcode it anywhere where it's always used...