# At which exact point is CMakeCache.txt created?

Tags: cmake, cmake-cache

[cmake set value of variable for first run after command "project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71123263/cmake-set-value-of-variable-for-first-run-after-command-project) prompted the present OP.
From the tests mentioned there, and others, I guess that on first run `CMakeCache.txt` is created when executing command `project`.

Could someone confirm/correct, quoting a reputable source?

Comment: `CMakeLists.txt` is a sequence of commands. 
I guess (maybe wrong) file `CMakeCache.txt` is actually created on first run when executing command `project ...`.
I guess I could put together tests, setting a wait time (if possible) at different points across `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that on first run CMakeCache.txt is created when executing command project.

It is not.

---

The CMake cache, if it exists, is read on program start-up. Otherwise it initializes only the following variables:

- CMake executables: `CMAKE_COMMAND`, `CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND`, `CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND`
- CMake generator info: `CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR`, `CMAKE_GENERATOR`, `CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE`, `CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM`, `CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET`
- CMake installation info: `CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY`, `CMAKE_ROOT`

See this test:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
get_property(vars DIRECTORY PROPERTY CACHE_VARIABLES)
message(STATUS "${vars}")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test NONE)
$ rm -rf build && cmake -S . -B build
-- CMAKE_COMMAND;CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND;CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND;CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR;CMAKE_GENERATOR;CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE;CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM;CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET;CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY;CMAKE_ROOT
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/build
```

The `project()` command will, naturally, create many cache entries related to the language and project metadata. At a minimum, with no languages enabled, it sets these variables:

- Platform information: `CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED`, `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`, `CMAKE_UNAME`
- Generator settings: `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`, `CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE`, `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`
- Installation settings: `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, `CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE`, `CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH`, `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH`
- Project metadata: `CMAKE_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION`, `CMAKE_PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL`, `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME`
- Project-relative paths: `${PROJECT_NAME}_BINARY_DIR`, `${PROJECT_NAME}_IS_TOP_LEVEL`, `${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR`

---

It will *not* however, write them to disk. Only when the program exits normally are the contents of the cache written out to disk. See this test:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test NONE)

get_property(vars DIRECTORY PROPERTY CACHE_VARIABLES)
message(STATUS "${vars}")

execute_process(COMMAND pkill cmake)

$ rm -rf build && cmake -S . -B build
-- CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE;CMAKE_COMMAND;CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND;CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND;CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS;CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR;CMAKE_GENERATOR;CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE;CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM;CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET;CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY;CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX;CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE;CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM;CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED;CMAKE_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION;CMAKE_PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL;CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME;CMAKE_ROOT;CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH;CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH;CMAKE_UNAME;CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE;test_BINARY_DIR;test_IS_TOP_LEVEL;test_SOURCE_DIR
Terminated
$ stat build/CMakeCache.txt
stat: cannot stat 'build/CMakeCache.txt': No such file or directory
```

Note that replacing the `pkill cmake` command with `message(FATAL_ERROR)` *does* persist the cache. Hence, the cache usually resides in memory. You should not need to care about when exactly the cache is persisted.