# The best way to include assimp library using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, assimp

I build my project using cmake (It is important for me to work both generators: Ninja and Visual Studio). And I need to add assimp library to my project. So, I added assimp from git to my project as git submodule and as suggested in the docs I added this lines to my CMake:

```cpp
add_subdirectory(assimp)
target_link_libraries(project assimp)
```

**I don't understand:**

1. By default assimp compiles as shared lib, so why I should use `target_link_libraries(rt assimp)`, if as far as i know it's link my executable with static library? And anyway after this linkage my .exe requires .dll.
2. Also, as alternative, I tried to compile assimp as static lib, as specified in the documentation I should use `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)`. I added this flag to my main CMakeLists.txt. But it still compiles two files:

- bin/Debug/assimp.dll
- lib/Debug/assimp.lib

```cpp
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
add_subdirectory(assimp)
target_link_libraries(project assimp)
```

I thought that I could choose one of them, but no: after linkage with static lib (`target_link_libraries(rt assimp)`) it's anyway requires .dll.

**Note:** .dll is uncomfortable for me, because I don't want to move the .dll to my .exe directory everytime. Also, variants like donwloading assimp from vcpkg or adding .dll to PATH don't work to me, because **my main goal** is: the user should just clone my git repo and compile the whole project with all dependecies using only one my CMakeLists.txt without additional actions.

Comment: ***Note: .dll is uncomfortable for me, because I don't want to move the .dll to my .exe directory everytime.*** You could script that using CMake.  Although this question is 10 years old there are some modern methods in the answers depending on the CMake version you support: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But, as for me its a little weird solution. Anyway, also Interesting to solve static lib problem.

Comment: ***Interesting to solve static lib problem*** I am not sure that it is a solvable problem. Not all libraries can be easily compiled into static libraries.

Comment: But the documentation mentions that I can compile static:
https://assimp-docs.readthedocs.io/en/v5.1.0/about/quickstart.html#assimp-static-lib

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to tell the executable where the .dll is (using cmake, without PATH) instead of move .dll to .exe directory?

Comment: ***is there a way to tell the executable where the .dll is (using cmake, without PATH) instead of move .dll to .exe directory?*** No. CMake does not control run time of your compiled executable.

Comment: This answer may work and not require any dll copying / moving depending on what the CMakeLists.txt does for assimp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445220/487892

Comment: Yes, its works. Also, interesting why in "shared compilation" there are two libs: .dll and .lib and I have to use both. Developers split the whole code into two parts: .lib and .dll?

Comment: With msvc a dll which uses implicit linking has an import library with a `.lib` file that you link. This library does not contain the implementations of the functions and requires a dll at runtime. You can try this tutorial to understand how this works: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Comment: To build a static version of assimp, set `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` to `OFF`, it's a standard option of CMake projects. By default it's OFF in CMake, but assimp changes the default value to ON: https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/v5.2.4/CMakeLists.txt#L63-L66

Comment: **Not all libraries can be easily compiled into static libraries** => usually it's the opposite, specially on Windows since many libraries don't properly export symbols.

Comment: Like I mentioned in question I tried, but it's didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766740/overriding-a-default-option-value-in-cmake-from-a-parent-cmakelists-txt

Comment: ***usually it's the opposite, specially on Windows since many libraries don't properly export symbols*** My point was if the library was designed to be a dll from the developers you may not always easily alter settings to have it build as a static library.

Answer (score 0):

Assimp has an option to specify the output directory of it's dll files.

In the assimp top level CMakeLists.txt

```
IF(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)
  SET(ASSIMP_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin" CACHE STRING "Path for runtime output files")
ELSE()
  SET(ASSIMP_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} CACHE STRING "Path for runtime output files")
ENDIF()
```

So I think the easiest solution to import assimp to your project is to set the CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY before using add_subdirectory to include all 3rd party libraries. And the all dlls will be export to the specified directory.

Say your executable is to be compiled in build/bin/, put the following code before you include all 3rd party libraries.

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

add_subdirectory(external/assimp)
add_subdirectory(external/another_libaray)
```

Comment: Besides, you can also change ASSIMP_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY by set(ASSIMP_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin CACHE STRING "")